# Move shape while key is down in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, transform, keydown

I want to move a shape in a window while user holds a key down.
I'm new to this so i tried this approach, but i can't change circle.RederTransform from my new thread, because it belongs to a different thread. How should it be done?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Matrix transformationMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
        private Thread myThread = null;
        private bool isGoing = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            isGoing = true;
            myThread = new Thread(HandleMyThread);
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            isGoing = false;
        }

        private void HandleMyThread(object obj)
        {
            while(isGoing)
            {
                transformationMatrix.Translate(10, 0);
                circle.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(transformationMatrix);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you want to use the `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` class for UI-thread safe timers.

Here is an example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);

        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        transform.X += 2;
        transform.Y += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with doing it by just using an `Invoke`...but there are better ways to do what you want to do.

Firstly, creating a thread each time you handle the `KeyDown` is inefficient...and could lead to problems...because it may take a while to create and schedule the `Thread`...thus a delay in your "thing" moving.

In addition it's possible for you to get in a mess with having multiple threads staying in existence. For instance, say someone was repeatedly pressing and releasing the key....in that case it's possible for "old" threads to still keep running...because `isGoing` flag is true....in other words, there is poor synchronization.

```
private void HandleMyThread(object obj)
{
    Action action = new Action( ()=>
    {
        transformationMatrix.Translate(10, 0);
        circle.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(transformationMatrix);
    };

    while(isGoing)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```